# Sharing GPU resources in code

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpgpu

My program uses OpenGL to draw on the screen. This task is low-intensive but latency-sensitive. Another CPU thread of my program makes some calculations which are highly-intensive but of low priority. I implemented this calculations using OpenCL to be run on GPU. Since then I observe too big visual latency with OpenGL drawing.

Is it possible to manage the GPU loading or to schedule tasks on GPU? I use AMD Radeon GPU. As far as I know, there is 'Device Fission' extension for OpenCL, which is helpful in such cases, but it is supported only for CPUs, isn't it?

Another thing I'm concerned with is that AMD System Monitor shows GPU occupancy at 55% level. So, in my opinion, there should be enough resources to run both parts, OpenGL and OpenCL, without stalling.

**Update.** I made a small experiment with my OpenCL kernel function. A global work size was restricted with a small enough number to guarantee that some computing units will be idle when an OpenCL kernel is running. To compensate that, each work-item do more job. So GPU now is less occupied but kernel works longer. As a result, OpenGL becomes slower. Hence, it looks like OpenGL drawing and OpenCL calculations can't be done concurrently. Where can I find the information which cards supports such functionality? What about NVIDIA GPUs?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your problem might be memory constrained. This will give a lot of noops on the GPU. The main bottleneck of the GPU is reading and writing to global memory, as well as copying data to and from the GPU.

To make sure you don't copy more data than necessary, see if you can put any shared data directly on the GPU if you are copying back and forth between host and device memory. How large data sets are you working on? Small datasets = low occupancy on the GPU, without much gain in performance over the CPU.

Most GPUs can also only do one task at a time, meaning you can't draw and calculate at the same time on all GPUs. So you will have to wait for the calculations be done before you can draw, and vica verca which of course introduces a small latency if you draw whenever possible/don't aim for a fixed FPS, but a FPS which is as high as possible.

Comment: OpenCL implementation gives a significant speedup when tested individually. However its combination with OpenGL is unsatisfactory.
Where can I find an information if my GPU can draw and calculate simultaneously? I use Radeon HD 58xx.

Comment: "Most GPUs can also only do one task at a time, meaning you can't draw and calculate at the same time on all GPUs." This is a somewhat unlucky wording both because it's technically not true (all reasonably new GPUs can at least do three different things at the same time -- process a set of workgroups, retire and set up another few, and run a DMA transfer), and because the driver coalesces most of this by having an asynchronous command queue (or several). Thus, even if the GPU technically _could_ only do one thing at a time, you would still be able to draw (i.e. submit) in the mean time.